# how to display user profile photo cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

i want to display user's profile photo in user's view template

plz help me 
this is my code

```
echo $this->Html->image('file' , array(
    'class'=>'img-responsive' ,
    'width'=>'500',
    'height'=>'500'
));
```

database field named [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Wgd.png) is the path of the picture

the database field is named file and for example the path of a picture file

is `img\ocr_10887926_926362867374383_1355265921_n.jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of the function is `image(string $path, array $options =[])`.

What you're doing is telling cake to output the *literal string* `'file'` as the path of the image instead of the *string contents* of the database field.

To use the data contained in the database field, you need to first retrieve it from the database (you don't show such code) or get it from the session if you store it there.

It could be something like `$this->Html->image($user->file);` if you're using CakePHP3 or `$this->Html->image($user['file']);` if you're using CakePHP2, assuming `$user` is the retrieved record.

PS. If nothing of the above makes sense, please take a step back and start reading some basics about PHP and then CakePHP. It will certainly pay off in the future.

Comment: i try it but it doesn't work 

have you another solution pleaze ?

Comment: No. Unless you explain what your tried and didn't work or show any real effort understanding the problem, you're on your own.

Comment: pictures are stored in webroot/img    and this is to code of the upload of pictures  $file = $this->request->data('file');
            if(!empty($file)){
                $webroot = 'img' . DS ;
                $dir = WWW_ROOT . $webroot;
             $filename = uniqid('ocr_').'.jpeg';
            
                if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir.$filename)) {


                    $rep = $webroot.$filename;
  $message = __('Image a été téléchargée.');    i tryed  $this->Html->image($user->file ) and  $this->Html->image($user['file']) and it doesn't work

Comment: Print your array $user. What is output?